# How to make information box and attach it with chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Is it possible to create a chart with d3.js as given in the attached picture? Especially the information box. The context is from a specific start and end date if the data is missing on date place a dot instead of a bar in the chart. The difficulty I am facing is to attach the information box with the dots using a line using d3.js.

The whole chart should be implemented using (SVG) d3.js.
Can anyone give a solution example with any dataset?
[image]

Comment: If this is a dc.js question, you would take D3 code like in @Ruben's answer and activate it in a posttransition or renderlet event handler. You'd leave extra space in the bottom margin for your box, and use the scales of the chart to figure out where the dots go, like in [this example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/bar-extra-line.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an example, hopefully it will be enough to get you started.

```js
const url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json"

const margin = {
  top: 30,
  left: 40,
  right: 40,
  bottom: 100
};
const width = 800;
const height = 300;

const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

const notice = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top + height})`)

notice.append('rect')
  .classed('notice-box', true)
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', margin.top)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', margin.bottom - margin.top);

const warning = notice.append('text')
  .attr('x', 10)
  .attr('y', margin.top + 30);

const format = d3.timeFormat("Q%q %Y")
const setWarning = (data) => {
  warning.text(`Missing data for ${data.map(d => format(d.date)).join(', ')}`);
  notice.selectAll('line')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('line')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('x1', d => x(d.date))
    .attr('y1', margin.top)
    .attr('x2', d => x(d.date))
    .attr('y2', y(0) - height);

  notice.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('fill', 'black')
    .attr('r', 3)
    .attr('cx', d => x(d.date))
    .attr('cy', y(0) - height);
}

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// Since v5 d3.json is promise-based, hence the change.
d3.json(url)
  .then(response => response.data)
  .then(data => data.map(([date, value]) => ({
    date: new Date(date),
    value: value
  })))
  .then(data => {
    data.filter(({
        date
      }) => date.getFullYear() >= 2000 && date.getFullYear() <= 2005 && date.getMonth() === 0)
      .forEach(d => d.value = null);

    x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(({
      date
    }) => date)));
    const barWidth = width / data.length;

    y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(({
      value
    }) => value))]);

    g.append('g')
      .call(d3.axisBottom().scale(x))
      .attr('id', 'x-axis')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`);

    g.append('g')
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .attr('id', 'y-axis');

    g.selectAll('rect')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .attr('x', d => x(d.date))
      .attr('y', d => y(d.value))
      .attr('width', barWidth)
      .attr('height', d => height - y(d.value))
      .style('fill', '#33adff');

    const missing = data.filter(({
      value
    }) => value === null);
    setWarning(missing);
  });
```

```css
#y-axis path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill: none;
}

#x-axis path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill: none;
}

.notice-box {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```